# Sketch 3 doesn't show artboards in the export window

Tags: sketch-app, artboard

[image]

When I click export, it only shows me 1 file that I can export instead of showing the 3 artboards that I have. How can I fix this? How do I go about exporting my artboards?

Comment: I don't use Sketch, but would not expect it to export more than one artboard at once - surely it just exports your current artboard?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see it looks like your artboards aren’t made exportable, and instead the export dialogue is showing you that one *slice* is exportable.

To make your artboards exportable, click them all and then press the “Make Exportable” button in the lower right corner of the Sketch canvas.

[image: Press this button to make your artboards exportable]